# Why the TreeSet can only hold one object when i push three in it?

Tags: jakarta-ee, treeset, java

I want to push some objects into a TreeSet(inside BigHeap class) but i got problem :

here is my Main class:

```
# --------- Print 3 -----------
Logger.info("items.size() = " + items.size()); 
for (Item item : items) {
  Long score = item.getScoreByQueryItems(queryItems);
  Long itemId = item.id;
  ItemCacheNode node = new ItemCacheNode(itemId,score);
  bigHeap.push(node);  <----- here is the push action ---------
  # --------------Print three times------------
  Logger.info("node.itemId = " + node.getItemId()); 
}
# ---------------Print 1----------
Logger.info("bigHeap.getTreeSet().size() = " + bigHeap.getTreeSet().size());
```

And here's my BigHeap.java:

```
public class BigHeap<T> {
 private TreeSet<T> treeSet;
 public BigHeap(Comparator<T> comparator){
   this.treeSet = new TreeSet<T>(comparator);
 }
 public void push(T o){
   treeSet.add(o);
 }
 public TreeSet<T> getTreeSet(){
   return this.treeSet;
 }
}
```

The problem is , why the bigHeap push three times(different objects) but only hold one object after all.

Comment: It sounds like all three of your `ItemCacheNode` objects compare as equal, so each one "knocks out" its predecessor. Can you post the contents of your `Comparator<ItemCacheNode>` implementation's `compare` method?

Comment: It is likely that the problem is with the comparator. It looks like the Set considers all 3 nodes equal.

Comment: Thanks guys...It's my Comparator<ItemCacheNode> cause the problem, They are equals objects.

Answer (score 0):

This would be something that could be attributed to the reason that `Set` doesn't allow for duplication of elements.

You are pushing objects of type `ItemCacheNode` into a `set` ADT named bigHeap. Now, when a new object is added to the set, as per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html),

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a
>   Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

An erroneous comparator would override the otherwise sounds equals method native to a `TreeSet` **iff** the Treeset is not correctly implemented using the `Set` interface. As per the aforementioned docs,

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

Your definition,

`private TreeSet<T> treeSet = new TreeSet<T>(comparator);`

ignores utilization of the interface and as a result, showed this erroneous functionality, by not complying with the general idea of non-duplication functionality of a `Set`.